# Can't use Custom array of objects typescript-react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Functional Component that retrieves a list of objects upon rendering. Then, I run a foreach loop with it and it works perfectly! Afterwards, I make http requests with each of these objects to make a new array of objects... But I can't use its foreach, as if I formatted something wrong. I printed both arrays to the console and they look different. Help Please!!

```
interface minterface
{result: string;
  res: number;
  pos: number;
}
let analyzedAppReviews: minterface[] = [];
```

```
    try {
  const { data } = await ailab.post(
    `text/classification/predict/${ailabKey}`,
    {
      text: reviewText,
    }
  );
  let aiLabObj = {} as ailabInterface
  aiLabObj.result = data.result;
  aiLabObj.confidence_score = data.confidence_score;
  aiLabObj.processing_time = data.processing_time;
  analyzedAppReviews.push(aiLabObj);
}
```

[2 array instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IflZu.png)
[array with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRIci.png)

Comment: I suspect that you are trying to use analyzedAppReviews before the promises have resolved.  You would need to use Promise.all() to resolve them all or you could make analyzedAppReviews be a state and make a setState call  to set each element when it is resolved.

Comment: I am printing the object that is being received inside the function. I can't create a statevariable for this one because I need to do independent http requests. It'd re-render a lot of times and ends crashing

Comment: Im adding another picture of the array with values

Answer (score 1):

As Linda suggested. I changed the foreach loop for a Promise.all since I had to make multiple http requests. Worked like a charm, thank you very much. This is the proper way to do it with axios :) Also, after a bit of searching, it's a big NO to use foreach loops to make http requests. To anybody thinking of using it for that. Promise.all guys!

```
    let requestsArray = reviews.map((review: { body: string }) => {
  const request = ailab.post(`text/classification/predict/${ailabKey}`, {
    text: review.body,
  });

  return request;
});
Promise.all(requestsArray).then((values) => {
  let tmpList = values.map((value: any) => {
    return value.data;
  });
```